# Classical analogy of a parallel transport

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, holonomy

In an attempt to understands some basic concepts about manifolds and differential geometry I encountered a concept of a parallel transport.

This perhaps may be very naive question, but could one consider an analogy to [the parallel transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport) (as defined in this Wikipedia article) being a ball rolling on a flat table surface? If so, is then such an example also an example of holonomy or not?

Comment: You're going to have to make your question *far* more specific. What vector field on a curve on the sphere do I get by rolling a ball on a flat table surface?